# How to use Twilio API in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, twilio-api

I am not able to install Twilio API package in VS Code.

I tried "twillio.rest as Client"

I have successfully generated auth sid and auth token too,
but the module is missing and I am not able to install it.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question? I'm not sure what you mean as VS Code is just the editor. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985401/how-to-install-twilio-via-pip) and [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python) if you want to install the twilio python SDK

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to install Twilio API package in VS Code.

VSCode is just an editor. You have to install the package in your python interpreter. Run command `pip install twilio` in your terminal after [choosing your current Python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Installing the package could solve ModuleNotFound error.